# Lagrange Newton Method Singular Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

i implemented the lagrange-newton method in python to find the problem to nonlinear optimizing problem for learning purposes.

But every guess i made a guess for the initial values the resulting Jacobimatrix is either directly singular or singular after one iteration.

i wanted to solve the following problem:

$$
\min x_1 + x_2$$
such that
$$x_1 + x_2 = 1,\quad
x_1 + 0x_2 = 0,\quad
x_1^2-x_1 = 0,\quad
x_2^2-x_2 = 0.
$$

I choose $x_1 = x_2 = l_1  = l_2 = l_3 = l_4 = 0$ for my first guess (l means the lagrange-multiplicator)

The resulting matrix for the equation system is in general form:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
2l_3 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2x_1-1 &  0\\
0 & 2l_4 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 2x_2-1\\
1 & 1 &  0&  0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 &  0&  0 & 0 & 0\\
2x_1-1&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0&  0\\
0 &2x_2-1&  0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$

As you can see if $l_3, l_4 = 0$ this is singular.
But after one iteration $l_3, l_4 = 0$ is zero for every guess i tried.

What is wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! In its present state, your question does not make much sense. For instance, minimizing $x_1+x_2$ under the condition that $x_1+x_2=1$ is not particularly difficult, so the purpose isn't either. The conditions you give yield $x_1=0$ and $x_2=1$. What are the $l_i$'s ? What is the matrix representing ?

Comment: This is just an example to test my implementation. But it still fails, so i can't progress to better examples. l_i's are the lagrangian multiplier for each constraint. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier). you want to find a the zero to the gradient to Lagrange function. The matrix is the Hessian matrix which you need to use newton-method

Comment: So you want to use the lagrangian $\mathcal L=x_1+x_2+l_1(x_1+x_2)+l_2x_1+l_3(x_1^2-x_1)+l_4(x_2^2-x_2)$ ?

Comment: yes exactly and i want to solve the optimizing problem using lagrangian. To solve the resulting non-linear system you need newton-method. The matrix in this system is the hessian matrix from above.

Comment: so what is the use of the newton system if the matrix is singular, what do to then and why does it happened? does this mean your solution diverged?

Comment: All right this a hessian matrix, so it is symmetric. If you diagonalize it, you will find the linear relationships between the values of $x_i$ and $l_i$ at the minimum.

Comment: What do you mean? But don't i need Newton Iteration? This Matrix seems to be always singular for all $l_i$, $x_i$ which makes Newton useless.